# Create Super Resolution image from multiple images using superres

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a sequence of images and I extract a card from it. After this process the card will be correctly aligned and projected back to a plane (`warpPerspective`). However the quality is too low to e.g. read text from that card. Thus I tried to use the superres module to increase the resolution, however the documentation is pretty shallow and I have yet to find out how I can pass multiple images to the algorithm.

I tried to implement a custom `FrameSource` which is basically an adapter to a `std::vector` but for some reason I get a segfault.

```
class InterFrameSource : public superres::FrameSource {
  std::vector<cv::Mat> frames;
  std::vector<cv::Mat>::iterator iter;

public:
  InterFrameSource(std::vector<cv::Mat> _frames) : frames(_frames)
  {
    reset();
  }

  virtual void nextFrame(OutputArray _frame)
  {
    _frame.getMatRef().setTo(*iter);
    ++iter;
  }

  virtual void reset() {
    iter = frames.begin();
  }
};
```

**Edit**
The `cv::Mat` are all CPU-only.

Comment: you never check for iter == end() ?

Comment: yes, you're right, but the segfault happens on the first call an there are elements in the vector, but good call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after two days I finally got it. I needed to inverse the copying logic:

```
virtual void nextFrame(OutputArray _frame)
{
  if (iter == frames.end()) return;

  iter->copyTo(_frame);
  ++iter;
}
```

Comment: Hi could you please share the full code you used to translate a video into frames ?

I'm working on making the super resolution code work but I can't seem to figure it out, this could help.

Comment: Sorry it's an older project, I don't have the source at hand anymore. But if I remember correctly I just combined the two source fragments in this question (just replace the `nextFrame` from the original question with the updated one).